# TinyMCE when adding bullets the bullets do not show in front end/view

Tags: tinymce

I have a website where bullets are automatically hidden in list elements

```
<ul>
<li>aSASa</li>
<li>ASDDAS</li>
<li>SADASD</li>
</ul>
```

Now I wonder if it's possible when adding a bullet using TinyMCE to automatically add a class on inline style to the list element that will enable bullts to show eg.

insteas of just adding `<ul>` timnymce should add `<ul style="list-style-type:circle;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You will need to figure out on what event you will do the following action (either using the setup tinymce init parameter or an own plugin):

```
$(editor.getBody()).find('ul').css('list-style-type','circle');
```

*Example* using the setup parameter and the onKeyUp event:

```
  setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, evt) {
         $(ed.getBody()).find('ul').css('list-style-type','circle');
    });
  },
```