# add inline css to body in tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm importing some html from a external source into tinyMCE. I have 2 questions:

If i do `tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand('mce_editor_0','mceSetContent', false, myVar);` and myVar has a doctype and header etc defined, it seems to just take the body content. Is this a correct behavior?

Since myVar has some inline css within its body tag and mceSetContent() doesn't import it, i need to pass it myself. So how can i add inline css to the body of a tinyMCE instance?

Thanks

Comment: I find very useful this approach with the "setup" variable

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986473/tinymce-when-adding-bullets-the-bullets-do-not-show-in-front-end-view

Answer (score 0):

This is correct bahaviour. What you paste goes into the editors iframe body. doctype and css stuff not. The only thing you could do about that is to use the paste setting [paste_preprocess](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste), filter your css stuff out and insert it into the editors ifram head.

Comment: No, i want to use inline css since it is about a newsletter. Anyway, i can add inlien css like that: $('#mce_editor_0').contents().find('body').attr('style', 'background-color: yellow'); thanks for the info though

Comment: Newsletter should be as simple as possible. Head might be cut off by some mail tools. External css file also isn't as save as inline css

Comment: true, go for it then. you  may want to check your tinymce settings valid_elements for the style atribute not to get stripped out